# Geofence region radius larger than MKCircle radius

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location, geofencing

I'm building an app that detects whether you are in a region that is drawn on the map. It seems that when I test it, the radius of the actual geofence region is larger than the circle I have drawn. My code is below:

```
 func setupGeoFence() {
    let radius = 150
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: 44, longitude: -79)
    geofenceRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: location.coordinate, radius: CLLocationDistance(radius), identifier: "location")
    removeRadiusCircle(mapView: mapView)
    addRadiusCircle(location: location, radius: CLLocationDistance(Float(radius)), mapView: mapView)
    geofenceRegion?.notifyOnExit = true
    geofenceRegion?.notifyOnEntry = true
    self.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: geofenceRegion!)
    self.locationManager.requestState(for: geofenceRegion!)
}
func addRadiusCircle(location: CLLocation,radius: CLLocationDistance, mapView: MKMapView){
    let circle = MKCircle(center: location.coordinate, radius: radius)
    let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
    pin.coordinate = location.coordinate
    mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
    mapView.add(circle)
}
```

Comment: You mean you physically checked locations outside of the geofence? What was the geofence's size, and how far where you? iDevices have various means of determining location, and geofences use the most power-efficient ones, which are the least accurate (I.e. GPS is not used, it relies on Wi-Fi and/or cell signals)

Comment: Im using the simulator and slightly changing the custom coordinates to test whether its inside or outside of my circle. It just seems that the geofenceRegion is larger than the actual circle drawn.

Comment: Again, what's the size of your geofence, and how far out are you simulating? Have you taken into account the simulated accuracy? If the two circles intersect it's perfectly normal...

Comment: The size is the radius I've defined which is 150m. The circles do intersect but the geofence region seems to extend almost 50 or more meters in every direction which seems like a lot when it comes to accuracy. I'm just wondering if the 150 is interpreted differently when passed into the geofenceRegion vs. the MKCircle

Comment: To answer your question re how far out I'm simulating: I'm only moving my location around 50 or so meters away from the drawn circle.

Comment: To assist in explaining, here is a link to a screenshot of my simulator: http://imgur.com/a/KqCXJ (this would be considered inside)

Comment: The geofence algorithm has some hysteresis built-in, so it isn't just how far outside the region you are but how long you have been outside the region. This is to avoid repeated entry/exit notifications when you are close to the edge. Are you just moving continually  until you get an exit or have you determined the 50m by moving to greater and greater distances and waiting to see if you get an exit?

Comment: I'm just moving continually until i get an exit